# FatFree Framework - The (unset) cast is deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated, internal-server-error, unset, fat-free-framework

I am having a system built in FatFree framework and I am having an error when running one of my scripts(error given below).

On research, I found two github posts related to this(listed below), but can't figure out how to fix the issue or where to make the changes to fix the issue. Could anyone help me please?

https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/1080

https://github.com/SSilence/selfoss/issues/983

```
Internal Server Error

The (unset) cast is deprecated

[ctdata/lib/base.php:2032] Base->error(500,'The (unset) cast is deprecated')
[ctdata/lib/base.php:1899] Base->{closure}(8192,'The (unset) cast is deprecated','/home/ezcomp5/public_html/ctdata/lib/db/sql.php',110,array('class'=>'DB/SQL','func'=>NULL,'path'=>'./','auto'=>'/home/ezcomp5/public_html/ctdata/lib/','file'=>'/home/ezcomp5/public_html/ctdata/lib/db/sql.php'))
[ctdata/lib/base.php:1899] require()
[ctdata/index.php:37] spl_autoload_call('DB\SQL')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just upgrade your version of Fat-Free Framework.
This error has been fixed in 3.6.3.
See https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thank you, just confirming since I haven't worked with fatfree before: we should download all the files github and overwrite the existing core files? Please advise.

Comment: Exactly. Alternatively, if you're familiar with Composer, you can `composer require bcosca/fatfree-core`.

Answer (score 2):

That is merely a deprecation warning for coercing NULL with `(unset)`.

See [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

For example

```
$uselessCoercion = 'Hello';
$uselessCoercion = (unset)$uselessStuff;

// is the same as
$uselessCoercion = NULL;
```

NB. It's mentioned that setting a variable to `NULL` before using `unset()` is actually a performance tweak (albeit pedantic). As that way, the original value is definitely erased from memory.

A deprecation note from the docs:

> The (unset) cast has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0. Note that the (unset) cast is the same as assigning the value NULL to the variable or call. The (unset) cast will be removed as of PHP 8.0.0.

If you're unable to change the code, you can just disable it in php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
```

Ideally, you should be fixing these issues but the above is pretty generic for a production server where you're wanting to hide any bad eggs

If you're unable to modify php.ini then maybe you're able to revert to a version lower than 7.2.0

Comment: It's not the same as `unset($uselessCoercion)`. The other examples will still keep `$uselessCoercion` defined but with a null-value, while `unset(...)` removes the variable completely, making it undefined.

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I was just studying garbage collection. It's not "completely" removed, as in it's still taking up space in memory, hence why it's arguably wise to set variables with large results to null first before unsetting if pedantic performance tweaks your kind of thing

Comment: Sure, it might still have some garbage left in the memory, but for the scope of the code, it's gone, undefined.

Comment: I just checked by creating a php.ini file with the contents error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATION & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING in the ctdata directory, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: It was `E_DEPRECATED` sorry